# Word VBA: Range.Characters.First.Delete delets 2 characters if the second character is a space

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete a fixed number of characters of a paragraph in MS Word. I came across a situation where the paragraph starts with some character as the first character and a space as the second character. When I select the paragraph range and execute `Range.Characters.First.Delete` the second character (space) also gets deleted instead of only the first one.

Does anyone know why this behaviour is taking place?

Comment: This is a smart cut and paste feature.  You can turn it off.

Comment: @freeflow thanks, this is the solution! Can you post an answer so that I can select it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to investigate the Advanced Options of Word File.Options.Advanced then scroll down to cut, copy and paste and open the settings for Smart Cut and Paste. Experiment with the options therein.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
.Range.Characters.First.Text = vbNullstring
```

or:

```
.Range.Words.First.Text = " "
```

Comment: This would turn Range into a String, which I do not want to happen.

Comment: No, it would not do that. That you claim it does shows you haven't tried it. The 1st approach simply deletes the first character; the 2nd simply replaces that and the trailing space with a space. Both retain the formatting applied to the original content.

Comment: sorry, you're right, I was too superficial! I tried it and it does indeed work as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Selection.Range.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

Comment: For some strange reason this deletes the whole Selection in my case. Anyway, the answer in the comment of @freeflow solves the problem.